# Html generated with Xslt losing layout ( BRs and Ps )

Tags: html, xslt

I was trying to layout some debug information for my reading in html using xslt... but it happened that everythin is being put on only one line!? Trying to figure out what is wrong I minimized the problem to this:

my xlst that can be applied to any dummy xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html><body><p>These<br/>words<br/>aren't<br/>seperated<br/>by<br/>BRs</body></html></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet
```

And contrary to what I expected, everything is on only one line without brs. Any obvious error that I am doing ?

Is it possible it is due to Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Not taking into the account the XML errors in your XSL, the words do end up separated by `br`s for me. http://www.xmlplayground.com/Qs7VJa

Comment: wow xmlplayground, nice site. going to play with it.

Comment: yep, it performs well on XmlPlayground, but not in Internet Explorer 9....

Comment: Stephane, how do you use the XSLT in IE 9 when it does not work, simply by loading an XML document with a `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sheet.xsl"?>` in a browser window? Or do you use some code to run the transformation? If so how does that code look?

Comment: I let IE9 do the work alone indicating the <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sheet.xsl"?> in the xml file I am loading. The code is exactly the one I pasted in my original post.

Comment: Stephane, that code is not well-formed so it can't work, it has an opening `<p>` tag that is not closed anywhere. So please post the real code or a URL to a sample we can visit that does not work as intended but is well-formed XML. I put up http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2012061401.xml and it works fine for me with IE 9 and FF.

Comment: Have you tried doing `<xsl:output method="html"/>`? Did you examine the DOM of the resulting page to see if the br's are present but just getting rendered for some reason? Try replacing the `<br/>` with something else (`<hr/>` say) to see if the problem is somehow br-specific. Etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XHTML as the default namespace to apply the default stylesheet to the p and br tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="html5.xml"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                >
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" version="" indent="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
      These<br/>words<br/>are<br/>seperated<br/>by<br/>BRs
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This self-contained stylesheet works when saved as html5.xml.